# liquid texels visible through glass - any solution?

Tags: physics

Successfully filled a glass with wine, and the liquid (wine) creates a nice smooth skin on top, but!... the bottom of the wine, which is also visible through the glass, doesn't bother to smooth out, and looks kinda lego'ish.

[image]

Any ideas on how to coax the liquid physics to apply its smoothness where the wine meets the surface of the glass?

Comment: Rendering with 2.8 EEVEE, btw. Although I imagine it's a matter of how the texels create polygons, i.e. irrelevant of render type.

Comment: Right you are! Thank you very much - looks like a solution.